# mon. dd, yyyy JavaScript conversion date function not working

Tags: javascript, html, date, google-chrome

i'm trying to convert `gen. 02, 2023` date in `2023-01-02` but my function formatDate:

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
```

doesn't seem to work properly.
Can you help me out?

It looks like i receive just `NaN-NaN-NaN` as value.

Comment: How do you call `formatDate`?

Comment: If you are actually saying that your input value for this is `gen. 02, 2023`, then - see duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You  used  `getMonth() method` to get the month number, but the month number is `zero-based`. So, the month number for January is 0, not 1. You need to subtract 1 from the month number before you pass it to the `formatDate() function.`

```
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = d.getMonth() - 1,
        day = d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}
```